# Xamarin.Forms Android change color of Button Image

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, renderer

I have a custom `ButtonRenderer` for Android and I want to change the color of the Image that I use for the button.

This is my `ButtonRenderer`:

```
public class VolosBaseButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer {
        public VolosBaseButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e) {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            // What I must do here for change the Image color????

        }

        protected override AppCompatButton CreateNativeControl() {
            var context = new ContextThemeWrapper(Context, Resource.Style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless);
            var button = new AppCompatButton(context, null, Resource.Style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless);
            return button;
        }    
    }
```

I tried these methods but none worked:

```
Control.Background.SetColorFilter(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Blue, global::Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);

Control.Background.SetTint(Color.Red.ToAndroid());
```

If it's possible I can apply a style at the button (but I don't know how to do it).

Any methods will be fine.

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't it just be button.SetColourFilter(Color.Blue, PortterDuff.Mode.SrcIn); not sure why you're using 'Control.Background', it's also not the background you're tinting on an image button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your custom Button has two properties, `CustomImage`, which stores a string of an resource image name, ie "icon.png", and another `ImageTintColor`, which stores a `Xamarin.Forms.Color` object, you can use it like so:

```
var button = (CustomButton)Control.Element;
using (var image = GetScaleDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(button.CustomImage.Split('.')[0]),
    (int)button.WidthRequest, 
    (int)button.HeightRequest))
{
    if (button.ImageTintColor != Xamarin.Forms.Color.Default)
        image.SetColorFilter(button.ImageTintColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);

    this.Control.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    this.Control.SetCompoundDrawables(null, image, null, null);
}
```